# Help with 出てしまって vis a vis people afflicted with disease

Tags: grammar, translation

> A: この国の夏暑いですから…大変でしょう？
>
> B: 最初はビックリしました
>
> B: 「夏バテ」…と言ったかしら
>
> ダウンする子も出てしまって
>
> 食事も気を使いますしね～

Preliminary translation:

> A: Summers are really hot here so…was it difficult for you?
>
> B: We were surprised at first.
>
> B: I think it's called... heat illness.
>
> Downed kids also **?!?!**
>
> I also had take care what I cooked for them.

Context: B has moved to Japan with family for the first time. It's July and apparently B's family had a rough time with Japanese heat.

The problem here for me is the **ダウンする子も出てしまって** bit. **ダウンする子** is kids/children/girls who were downed by the illness. But I don't really get what **出てしまって** is doing here. Literally, and out of context, it would probably mean something like, completely leave. But if I would use one of the movement verbs to say someone got ill, I'd say someone got in/got under illness.

So what is it's meaning here?!?

PS: Yeah, I know 出る has a lot of the meanings but I'm not sure which one would apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ダウンする is shown on Weblio as 'to knock down'. In this case, it would read as 'Kids who have been knocked down' or 'Kids who have been affected'. What they have been knocked down by is the summer heat （夏バテ）.

Some of the uses of 出る are to say that something has 'appeared', 'been revealed', 'shown itself', or more relevant: 'been produced'.

While the translation that I would suggest would be 'Some children have been negatively affected by the summer heat, we're careful regarding what they eat.', I think other (more paraphrased) translations such as 'Some kids have become ill from the heat. One must be cautious with their diet.' would also be fine.

Comment: This seems a legit answer. Wonder why it got downvoted and the downvoter didn't provide any info on why?!?

Comment: Mayhaps someone will enlighten us.

Comment: Whelp. Since noone wants to correct us. Here you go.